# what's to do with "GPU not found. Falling back to CPU device"

Tags: opencl, video-card

Just downloaded `AMD-APP-SDK-v2.5-RC2-lnx32`, why i got this: `GPU not found.` , when i try to execute a sample program ?

```
%> ./AESEncryptDecrypt
Platform 0 : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Encrypting Image ....
Input Image : input512.bmp
Key : 15 201 51 89 92 34 96 66 11 225 161 96 81 211 108 124 
GPU not found. Falling back to CPU device

Selected Platform Vendor : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Device 0 : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5870  @ 2.00GHz
Executing kernel for 1 iterations
-------------------------------------------
Output Filename : output.bmp
```

==========================================

fglrxinfo:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series
OpenGL version string: 3.3.10665 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the Radeon HD 3400 hardware does not support ["ATI Stream Processing"](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/STREAM-TECHNOLOGY/Pages/stream-technology.aspx) (and thus OpenCL on the GPU).

See [How to enable OpenCL-GPU-processing in Linux (CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)?](http://forums.amd.com/devforum/messageview.cfm?catid=390&threadid=145730) (It is only supported on [certain cores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_FireStream), and there are multiple cores -- with different features enabled -- used within a `Fxxx` model range).

Happy OpenCL-on-CPU coding.